# WebGL extensions in a child window

Tags: html, webgl

I'm trying to render a scene with webgl in a popup window. My shaders don't work because of missing derivatives extension. I can't find any information on why some extensions (all?) would not be supported like this. Is there a reason that this is no longer working or am I doing something wrong?

How can i get rid of:

```
'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
```

In a child window?

Comment: how to use derivatives in a canvas thats being rendered in a child window?